# mui autocomplete - how do i sort selected options on top?

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I'm using mui's useAutocomplete hook

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#useautocomplete

Is it possible to sort options and put selected on top with actual js sorting not flex order or any css workaround?

I have tried using

```
filterOptions = (options, { inputValue })
```

however current selection state is notpassed here

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=react-mui+sort+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score -1):

friend! I had the same problem and this is how I solved it:

```
 const arrOfChechedItems = [Your checked items by onChange or what do you have];
    const sortItems = (id: string) => {
    const a = arrOfChechedItems?.find((item) => item === id);
    if (a) return -1;
    if (!a) return 1;
    return 0;
  };
```

Before you map the list:
arr**.sort((a) => sortItems(a.id)).**map